# index.php/argument not found - strange issue with apache

Tags: apache, indexing, http-status-code-404

when passing parameters after index.php its showing 404 error .. its apache error not the cms
but there is no problem accessing index.php directly

```
File does not exist: /home/me/web/test/index.php/a
File does not exist: /home/me/web/test/index.php/home
File does not exist: /home/me/web/test/index.php/contact
```

problem doesn't related to mod_rewrite because I am getting same error when index.php is in the URL ..

using .htaccess and mod_rewrite and removing index.php from url doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not making totally clear where those URLs come from, but from the looks of it,  your web server's [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive isn't "On".

> This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the PATH_INFO environment variable.